# Reading KML file with Multiple Folders using geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have a KML file with multiple folders in it. I can't get geopandas to read each folder; I could only get it to read the first folder using read_file(filename, driver="KML")

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
import fiona
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gdf=gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\Asad16\Desktop\Final_Maps.kml",driver="KML")
print(gdf)
```

I want all folders within the KML file to show, not just the top folder.

Comment: There is some useful info here: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/97

Comment: I followed https://www.igismap.com/convert-kml-shapefile-qgis/ to get to a .shp file. Guess this is not enough for an answer :-/

Comment: Your Problem has been solved here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328525/geopandas-read-file-only-reading-first-part-of-kml